# Angular templates with data

Tags: angular

A parent component passes 2 templates and data to a child component. In the child component only the template without data is shown. How to show the template with data passed to it?

Parent component file:

```
export class ParentComponent {
  parentdata: string = 'String from parent with data';
  constructor() { }
}
```

Parent html/template file:

```
<app-child2
  [templateHeader]="list"
  [templateContent]="detail"
  [datafromparent]="parentdata">
</app-child2>

<ng-template #detail>
  Some data passed to it from outside
</ng-template>

<ng-template #list let-data="datafromparent">
  {{data}}
</ng-template>
```

The child component is: yup, will remove the ts-ignore ;-)

```
export class Child2Component {
  // @ts-ignore
  @Input() templateHeader: TemplateRef<any> | null;
  // @ts-ignore
  @Input() templateContent: TemplateRef<any> | null;
  @Input() datafromparent: string | undefined;
  constructor() { }
}
```

The child html/template file is:

```
<div class="header-css-class">
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="templateHeader; context: { data: datafromparent }">
  </ng-container>
</div>
<div class="content-css-class">
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="templateContent">
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

I hope you can help me with this one, because it is quite instructive for solving many (generic) problems.

Comment: Could you please post the full component code or add a stackblitz url?

Comment: It is already solved. See below. Thank you for willing to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the name of the data item from the context passed to the template (for clarity I changed the name from data to datafromcontext):

```
// in the child template
<ng-container
   *ngTemplateOutlet="templateHeader; context: { datafromcontext: datafromparent }">
</ng-container>

// in the parent template
<ng-template #list let-data="datafromcontext">
  {{data}}
</ng-template>
```